# 3d virtual exhibition stand

Tags: website-design, 3d, javascript, website-templates, blender

I would like to make an online 3d virtual exhibition stand (visitors of the website should be able to "go" through the 3D stand-model and by chance click on the items or watch the videos on the screens, like in a real booth). I can do the 3D model by myself (in Blender),but I'm not sure if there is a software, which "transform" my 3D model for such website-use. Does anyone have any advice for me?

Thanks

Comment: What about Second life?

Answer (score 2):

When I was tasked with creating a virtual trade show a year or so ago. I found the easiest solution was to create 360° Panoramic Images. I created the full show in Blender and exported using an equirectangular camera with the Cycles render engine. Unfortunately Eevee doesn't have this camera view. If you really want to use Eevee, you could export multiple camera angles and stitch them with another program.

I then made an interactive tour using software called Pano2VR. This is similar to Google Street View. You can add clickable spots that the user can click on to visit other booths or another spot that goes to a Keynote speaker.

There are a lot of features that probably cover what you're looking for like adding videos or images/products that people can click on for more information. In my experience, I found creating a virtual tour much easier to learn how to make compared to learning Unreal Engine or something similar. Another benefit is the user doesn't have to download anything to view the trade show.

If you want the users to be able to walk around an actual trade show floor in 3D, then maybe it's feasible for you to learn Unreal Engine.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Pano2VR is a really good and user-friendly solution, I think I'll try it.